# SQLAlchemy: exclude a column from being pickled

Tags: sqlalchemy, pickle

Is it possible to mark a column as do-not-pickle in SQLAlchemy, such that it will get loaded from the database on demand after it is unpickled instead?

This can be partially achieved with a `deferred` column, but if the column is subsequently loaded it will also then get pickled.

(I'm asking as it looks like there's still a problem in Python2.7 with pickling Geoalchemy2 Geometry columns due to the unpickleable nature of the built in `buffer`: https://github.com/geoalchemy/geoalchemy/issues/24 )

Comment: You can just override [`__getstate__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) to control which attributes are pickled.

Comment: My class is quite complex, lots of columns and multiple inheritance. I can't find an example of how to call the 'default' version of `__getstate__` to do it properly. I've written up my attempt in an answer along with the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little bit involved because you can't just prevent pickling of a column, since what controls the deferred loading is actually in the `_sa_instance_state` attribute, so even if you don't pickle some attribute in your instance dictionary SQLAlchemy does not know that that means it's expired.

A (slightly hacky) solution is to expire the attribute when you unpickle:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo = Column(String)
    bar = Column(String)

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {k: v for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if k != "bar"}

    def __setstate__(self, d):
        for k, v in d.items():
            self.__dict__[k] = v
        self._sa_instance_state._expire_attributes(self.__dict__, ("bar",))
```

Note that the result of unpickling is a detached instance, so you need to be careful how you use it:

```
foo = session.query(Foo).first()
foo = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(foo))
print(foo.foo)  # fine
# print(foo.bar)  # sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError
foo = session.merge(foo, load=False)
print(foo.foo)  # no query
print(foo.bar)  # causes a query
```

Comment: Super! Would be great if this was an attribute on the Column but I guess that's a feature request. zzzeek ftw :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a naive `__getstate__` implementation that doesn't work, but will hopefully prompt the right answer:

```
Base = declarative_base(metadata=route_metadata)

cols_to_omit = ['my_col_1']

class MyClass(Base):

    my_col_0 = Column(Integer)
    my_col_1 = Column(Integer)

    def __getstate__(self):
        return dict((c, getattr(self, c)) for c in \
              self.__table__.columns.keys() \
              if c not in cols_to_omit)

    def __setstate__(self, *args):
        for c, v in args[0].items():
            setattr(self, c, v)


from pickle import *
pp = dumps(MyClass.query.first())
obj = loads(pp)
```

This gives `AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'`